# Exercise 2.2.2 in Analysis I Terence Tao

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Exercise 2.2.2: Prove Lemma 2.2.10. (Hint: use induction. The induction here is somewhat degenerate, in that the induction hypothesis is not actually used, but this does not prevent the argument from remaining valid; cf. the discussion on implication and causality in Appendix A.2)

Lemma 2.2.10: Let a be a positive number. Then there exists exactly one natural number b such that b++=a.

My proof:

- By Def 2.2.7 of positive numbers, a is not 0, so it may have a predecessor.
- Also a is a natural number, so by Axiom 2.4, a has a unique predecessor (if n++=m++, then n=m.)

My questions:

1. Is the above proof valid? I feel I might have missed a subtle point.
2. Why do we use Proposition 2.2.8? My proof didn't need it.
3. Why do we use induction? My proof didn't need it.

Some of the preceding context:
[image]

Text [here](https://math.unm.edu/%7Ecrisp/courses/math401/tao.pdf).

Comment: I think it is obligatory to explain the operator +, as it is being used both a binary operator, qua $a+b$, and as part of the unary operation $b++$.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean in my proof, or in my post in StackExchange? If the latter: ++ refers to an "increment operation" Tao defines before defining addition (which he defines recursively using ++). If the former, I'm not using + as a binary operator in the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is wrong, you have not actually showed that every positive number has a predecessor, the first bullet point of your proof only means that if you have a number that is a predecessor, then it needs to be positive, but not the converse, and Axiom 2.4 shows that if the predecessor exists, it is unique, but it doesn't guarantee that it exists. What you have to do is prove by induction the statement that if $n$ is positive, then it has a predecessor, and you can do it in the following way:

Base case: if $n=0$, then $n$ is not positive, so there is nothing to show here.

Inductive step: suppose that if a number $n$ is positive, then it has a predecessor, and consider $n++$. We only have to observe that $n++$ has $n$ as its predecessor, so the statement is satisfied for $n++$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more about why you are allowed to use $n=0$ as a base case, when we are told $a$ is a positive number? I would imagine you could only start at $n=1$ as a base case. Would it have worked whether I chose $0$ or $1$ as my base case?

Comment: And, does Tao call the induction "degenerate" because when you state "we only have to observe that $n++$ has $n$ as its predecessor," we didn't need the inductive hypothesis to observe this?

Comment: @FlyingSpaghetti If you check Axiom 2.5, you can see that the form of induction stated by it always starts with the base case $n=0$. Of course, you can use induction from a number $k$ onwards, but to prove this form of induction you use Axiom 2.5, and at least the beginning of the proof is similar, because if $k>0$, then for $n=0$ you must prove nothing and go to the inductive step, so if you use this form of induction, it will be essentially the proof I showed you (with the additional fact that every positive number is $\ge 1$). And yes, that's the reason why induction is called degenerate.